# React making single call to window.parent.postMessage results in angularjs controller receiving multiple messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, iframe

I'm working in a project that is transitioning from angularjs to ReactJS and have a page where the React components are in an iframe that posts messages to the underlying angular controller. On the React side, when an action is triggered it calls into the angular controller using:

```
window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
```

Then on the angular side, I set up a listener:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveReactMessage, false);
```

The angular side does receive the messages, and the appropriate function is called, the problem is that while I've verified the React side only calls postMessage once, the angular side receives 10 or even more (it's not totally consistent how many) messages, and so attempts to perform the function many times.

I made sure I didn't just have 10 listeners and also tried changing the listener add part to:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveReactMessage, { useCapture: false, once: true });
```

But that doesn't prevent it from happening. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

EDIT: Here is the React code that makes the call, when the option is selected it calls:

```
  const execute = (items: any[]) => {
    sendMessage({
      type: actionTypes.EXECUTE,
      payload: { items },
    });
  };
```

And sendMessage is:

```
export default (message: { type: string; payload: any }) => {
  try {
    window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Could not post message to parent iframe : ', error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Were is your React code, were you are adding the event?

Comment: @Keith I added the react functions to my post so you can see - if I set a breakpoint in the sendMessage function or add a log message, it seems to only be called one time. So in a nutshell, execute gets called once, but then receiveReactMessage gets called many times.